# $f(x)=(x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ domain integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)=(x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. Then find the number of integers that are not in the domain of $f(x)$.

My approach  $f(x)=(x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1)>0$ as the denominator cannot be equal to zero.

Comment: I am not able to find the roots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(x)=x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1$ and let $x$ be an integer.

Case 1: $x \le 0$. Then $x^{12}+x^4+1 >0 > x^9+x$, hence $g(x)>0$.

Case 2: $x \ge 1$. Then $x^{12}+x^4+1 \ge x^9+x^4+1 \ge x^9+x+1 >x^9+x$, hence $g(x) >0$.

Conclusion: $g(x)>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 3):

$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\bigg[2x^{12}-2x^9+2x^4-2x+2\bigg]$

$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\bigg[\bigg(x^{12}-x^6+\frac{1}{4}\bigg)+\bigg(x^{12}-2x^9+x^6\bigg)+x^4+\bigg(x^4-x^2+\frac{1}{4}\bigg)+(x^2-2x+1)+\frac{1}{2}\bigg]$

$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\bigg[(x^6-0.5)^2+(x^{6}-x^3)^2+x^4+(x^2-0.5)^2+(x-1)^2+\frac{1}{2}\bigg]>0\;\;\forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$